# swift Generics with protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I created a function with generics

```
func sorted<T: MyProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [T] { ... }
```

and trying to call in

```
let array: [MyProtocol] = [...]
let sortedArray = sorted(array: array)
```

But getting the error

```
Type 'any MyProtocol' cannot conform to 'MyProtocol'
```

I understand that variable `array` is a box that can contain any kind of thing that conforms to the `MyProtocol`. But how I can resolve this problem ? I need to sorted any kind of `MyProtocol`

Tried something like this, but do not working

```
func sorted<T: any MyProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [T] { ... }
```

Comment: What does the `MyProtocol` do? If you're looking to sort an array then I would start from adding this as a function to the array rather than a free function that you pass an array into. `let array = myArray.sorted()` rather than `let array = sorted(myArray)`. Is that not possible for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a function to `Array` based on the `Element` you could do that by extending the array...

```
extension Array where Element: MyProtocol {
  func sorted() -> [Element] {
    // put your sorting logic here that uses the `MyProtocol` properties.
  }
}
```

Having said that though... if you can sort objects that conform to your `MyProtocol`. Then that protocol also will probably conform to `Comparable`.

And there is already a `sorted` function on `[Comparable]` (Array of objects conforming to `Comparable`). So you wouldn't need a new function for that.

To make that work you could define your protocol like...

```
protocol MyProtocol: Comparable {
}
```

This will then give your array the `.sorted()` function.

Documentation on Comparable... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but i can't use sort in extension cuz the sorting very specifically and need to use a private properties of own class (function `sorted` is in other private class)

Comment: @akexjeer the `Comparable` protocol just defines the `>` function which is implemented in the class/protocol itself. If you can define a function to compare two objects conforming to `MyProtocol` then you can use the `array.sorted()` function. If you can't do that then you need to update your question to tell us these things as we can't guess what constraints you have added to your code. This answer answers the question you asked. If you asked the wrong question you can update it to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that variable `array` is a box that can contain any kind of thing that conforms to the `MyProtocol`.

That's exactly the problem with your code. When you wrote `let array: [MyProtocol]`, rather than having an array of some concrete type that adopts the `MyProtocol` protocol, it is actually an array of an **existential type** that can store any objects that adopt the `MyProtocol` protocol, and such existential type does not adopt the protocol itself.

However, when you wrote the generic function `func sorted<T: MyProtocol>`, you specifically constrained the type `T` to be some type that adopts `MyProtocol`. Since the existential type itself does not adopt the protocol, you received the error.

---

To solve the problem, instead of constraining the function `sorted`, you can make the parameter itself and the return value an array of the existential type:

```swift
func sorted(array: [MyProtocol]) -> [MyProtocol]
```

---

Sidenote, starting from Swift 5.6, usages of existential types should be explicitly denoted, so your `array` declaration would become:

```swift
let array: [any MyProtocol] = [...]
```

And the function signature would become:

```swift
func sorted(array: [any MyProtocol]) -> [any MyProtocol]
```

Comment: @akexjeer Note if the only task is to sort the array, the best approach is to make the `MyProtocol` [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable), as suggested in **@Fogmeister**'s answer, and you don't even need to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: honestly, i do in the project like your answer, but with some modifications

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that the type of the elements in the array variable, any MyProtocol, is not the same as the type specified in the sorted function's generic constraint, MyProtocol.

In Swift, any is a protocol that all types conform to. So any MyProtocol is a type that conforms to both the any and MyProtocol protocols.

To fix this error, you can either change the type of the array variable to [MyProtocol] or change the constraint of the sorted function to T: any MyProtocol.

Comment: let array: [MyProtocol] = [...]
let sortedArray = sorted(array: array)

Comment: func sorted<T: any MyProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [T] { ... }
let array: [any MyProtocol] = [...]
let sortedArray = sorted(array: array)

Comment: You can change the type of the array variable to [MyProtocol]
Or if your protocol is inherit from another protocol you can use that in the function definition like func sorted<T: MyProtocol & AnotherProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [T] { ... }

Comment: thank you for the answer, but if a write `func sorted<T: any MyProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [T] { ... }` a have the error `Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'any MyProtocol'`

Comment: The any protocol is the base protocol for all types in Swift, so it cannot be used as a constraint for a generic type.

Comment: A possible solution is to create a new protocol that inherits from MyProtocol and use that in the constraint of the sorted function instead.